# Nissan Qashqai 1.5dci Electrical issues

Tags: engine, electrical, nissan, lights, steering-wheel

I'm experiencing fluctuating lights in the car, blocking steering wheel while using servo in low gears, really slow window rolls and the front light are losing intensity while steering the wheel.

The mechanic just repaced the alternator, but the issues are still ocurring. Any idea on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like either your battery voltage is low or has a bad connection at the battery terminals or ground connection to the engine/chassis. Did the mechanic check the battery voltage? The battery voltage should be between 12.4-12.7 volts and you can check the voltage if you have a multimeter. You can visually inspect the battery terminals to make sure they are clean and have a solid connection. Another thing you might want to check is to make sure the drive/serpentine belt is not slipping. Any of the above would reduce battery voltage going to the electronic components of the vehicle and cause the issues you described.

Comment: Just checked the voltage, 11.9 V with the engine not running and 14.3 with it at idle. The bad drops in voltage ocurr while driving the car, the servo is turning off and lights appear in the board. At this point it is undriveable and the mechanic does not want to come where I am and inspect it. Can the issues be caused by the battery even though this occurs while driving?

Comment: Your battery needs to be replaced.  11.9 volts indicates your battery is only 40% charged.  Modern day cars the battery and alternator work in concert with one another to power your car's electronics. On the plus side your alternator seems to be working as it should.

Comment: Thanks, just followed your advice and replaced the battery, now the car is working. Still a little concerned about the fact that the steering wheel returns aggresively when I reach the end  of the spin and it sometimes blocks when on low rpm. But for now, at least, it seems to be starting and working. I'm grateful for the advice!

Comment: Happy to be able to help!